# How to display a row if value is true

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi guys wondering if you guys could help me,

i have a  `<p:panelGrid columns="2">` and one thing i would like to do is if the country is united kingdom then display the postcode row, but for all other countries do not display and i want to do this with out the user having to press any buttons

```
                <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.country}" for="Countries" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="Countries" 
                                 value="#{bean.addressToCreate.country}"                                     
                                 valueChangeListener="#{country.countryLocaleCodeChanged}" 
                                 filter="true" 
                                 filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{country.countryInMap}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.labelPostcode}" for="Postcode" />
                <p:inputText id="Postcode" 
                             validator="PostcodeValidator"
                             value="#{bean.addressToCreate.postcode}" 
                             title="#{bundle.labelPostcode}" 
                             required ="True"
                             requiredMessage="#{bundle.requiredPostcode}" />
```

above is currently my code, but i am wondering how to do this so any help would be much appreciated, the list of the countries is stored into a backing bean

thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use the `rendered` attribute for that purpose. It allows you to render components, depending on one or more conditions.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="Countries" value="#{bean.addressToCreate.country}"   valueChangeListener="#{country.countryLocaleCodeChanged}" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                <p:ajax update="postcodePanel" event="valueChange"/>
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{country.countryInMap}" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>

                                <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.labelPostcode}" for="Postcode" />
        <p:outputPanel id="postcodePanel">
        <p:inputText rendered="#{bean.addressToCreate.country=='use your own spelling for UK here'}" id="Postcode" validator="PostcodeValidator" value="#{bean.addressToCreate.postcode}" title="#{bundle.labelPostcode}" required ="True"
    requiredMessage="#{bundle.requiredPostcode}" />
    </p:outputPanel>
```

In your case, as you have a valueChangeListener you could programmatically update the outputPanel from there , see [RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html#update%28java.lang.String%29).